# Drill down into multi-nested arrays syntactic sugar

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, syntactic-sugar, ecmascript-2016

I often find myself following this pattern when I need to drill down into a data-structure, especially in my Redux reducers:

```
state.items = state.items.map((item) => {
  item.subItems = item.subItems.map((subItem) => {
    subItem.bottomItems = subItem.bottomItems.map((bottomItem) => {
      // do something with bottomItem...
      bottomItem.foo = 'bar';
      return bottomItem;
    });
    return subItem;
  });
  return item;
});
```

This seems like a lot of boilerplate to get down to the `bottomItems` level.

Does ES6 or ES7 provide some syntactic sugar to ease this pattern?

Comment: Well, you probably don't want to mutate the state itself :). Are you updating every bottomItems for every subItem for every item or something more specific?

Comment: @nem035 I actually wasn't quite aware that my mutations there were not best-practice... Thanks for bringing that to my attention. Yes, I'm trying to update every `bottomItem`

Comment: What you are looking for are *lenses*, a composable abstraction for drill-down. They aren't officially standardised or provide any syntactic sugar though, they need to be implemented in userland.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I should mention is that the code you have there modifies the original state. To maintain the [state immutability principle](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html#single-source-of-truth) of redux, you want to only return new objects and not modify existing ones along the way.

As far as a simpler syntax, if you use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [object spread](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread), this pattern isn't that bad:

```
return {
  items: state.items.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    subItems: item.subItems.map(subItem => ({
      ...subItem,
      bottomItems: subItem.bottomItems.map(bottomItem => ({
        ...bottomItem,
        foo: 'bar' // update foo to 'bar' for every bottomItem in every subItem in every item
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Note that object spread is not part of the language yet, it is currently a stage 3 proposal and will likely be part of one of the next ECMAScript releases. Therefore, you must transpile it with something like Babel to work in today's browsers.

If you do not wish to do this and want features natively available today, you can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) instead:

```
return {
  items: state.items.map(item => Object.assign({}, item, {
    subItems: item.subItems.map(subItem => Object.assign({}, subItem, {
      bottomItems: subItem.bottomItems.map(bottomItem => Object.assign({}, bottomItem, {
        foo: 'bar' // update foo to 'bar' for every bottomItem in every subItem in every item
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Since it seems that you want a cleaner, more readable syntax, I suggest option 1 :)

Comment: The OP asked for ES6/ES7 solutions though

Comment: @nem035 is the first code sample missing some parens? For example, the last closing paren seems to line up with the opening paren after `subItem => `

Comment: That's on purpose. If you have an arrow function that returns an object, the short syntax is like this `() => ({ /* object props */ })`, rather than the more verbose `() => { return { /* object props */ } }`

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, nested immutable updates can be a pain (as I mentioned in the [Structuring Reducers - Immutable Update Patterns](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html) section of the Redux docs).

You may want to look into using one of the many immutable update utility libraries out there.  Those libraries provide a variety of syntaxes and abstractions for doing simpler nested immutable updates.  Some use string key paths, others use nested object definitions.  A typical example might be `someLib.set(["items", "subItems", "bottomItems", 0, "someField"], someValue)`.

See the [Immutable Data#Immutable Update Utilities](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/immutable-data.md#immutable-update-utilities) section of my [Redux addons catalog](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links) for a list of libs that are available.